# c# How can i detect end of page in a Word document with Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I´m developping with c# Interop Word, and I need to know when a page ends, because I´m creating a Word Table. Rows number isn´t always the same,and if the page doesn´t end, then I have to insert a break page.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you define what a page is? There are paragraphs and special line breaks but the flow to fill a page will also be determined by font sizes and page size values..

Comment: how can I get the page size value ? I think that is my problem.

Comment: Page size is a document property but it is in physical units, not in lines. Things get a lot easier if your lines have a fixed height.

Comment: I have a fixed height:                                                                                               
       float cent = (float)0.42;
            var centimetres = wordApp.Application.CentimetersToPoints(cent); and now, how do I know the maximum number of lines ?

Comment: You will have to talk to the printer driver about the page size. But, since you also have tables and images this could get even more complicated..

Comment: Do I correctly interpret your question to mean that a table should be completely on one page, not break over to another page?

Comment: You need to use the  .Information method of the range.  This allows you to get the page number of the range (several options available).  You determine if you are on a new page by checking if the page number of the current range is greater than the page number of the range you set as a reference.

Comment: I solved it, because I got a problem with Word Template, but I wanted to have control on page end.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `Streamreader` to read your word file, you can do this:

```
string path = @"C:\..."; // the path of your word file
Streamreader sr = new Streamreader(path);
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
    // what you want to do
{
sr.Close();
```

If you want to know at what line your file ends, you just create a `count` value and when your file ends, you check the value of the `count` and you have it:

```
string path = @"C:\..."; // the path of your word file
int count = 0;
Streamreader sr = new Streamreader(path);
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
    // what you want to do
    count++;
{
sr.Close();
```

Comment: What has this to do with pages??

Comment: @lok-ridgmont thank you for your answer, but I´m writing in this Word File, with tables, images, paragraphs... and I just want to know when I reach the end of a page.